# Using C++ dll functions to improve performance in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, performance, image-processing, dllimport

For years a have heard that C++ is fast, so, it is good for image processing, by example.

If i am developing a system in C# that need to do some image processing and i want to improve your performance, whats the best aproach?

1 - Do it all in C# and do the image processing function embraced with "unmanaged"

2 - Write the function that process de image in C++ and import this function to my C# code?

Another questions?

Which one improves the performance?

Comment: Oh if only optimization was that easy... for starters, one can (and many of us will) write awfully inefficient code in *every* language.

Comment: This is pretty broad for Stack Overflow, there's a lot of room for discussion here. Can you narrow this down to one _objectively_ answerable question? It will likely be closed otherwise.

Comment: Ok Tim Post, i edited my question, i think it is generaly yet, but i dont know another best way to ask this.

Comment: The problem with performance is that it is hard to accurately predict what the bottleneck will be, and trying to optimize anything that isn't a bottleneck is usually a waste of time (or worse, introduces bugs, maintenance issues, etc).  Write it in the most natural way first, see if it is fast enough; if not, then profile, find the bottleneck, try an optimization, profile again.. rinse and repeat until performance is 'good enough'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a trade off between C++ to C# call and IL code to machine code generation.

1. C# generates IL code, which will be converted to machine code at run time. machine code generation will have some cost.
2. From C#, You can call C++ DLL's method. Loading C++ method and calling that will have some cost.

Now you need to compare the cost of 1 & 2.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know  what kind of image processing operations you need to do, but if you want to get a very good performance, you could consider in using CUDA or OpenCL (programming on the graphic card)